Selenium Xpath not working for automated test
I am creating a robot to autologin in a website.
So far it is working well, but I need to click in a button in the top of the screen and it is not working
The code from google inspect page is
<div class="remoteQuickAction ng-isolate-scope dropdown-toggle" action-title="Keyboard" action-image="keyboard-white" uib-dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="" xpath="1">
<div class="xcc-icon-keyboard-white" style="position:relative;top:2px"> </div>
<div class="remoteDisableSelection ng-scope" translate="Keyboard" style="">Keyboard</div>

And I already tried to set the XPATH as
//div[@action-title='Keyboard']
(//div[@action-title='Keyboard'])[1]
//*[@id="toolbar2"]/div[4]/div
//*[@id="toolbar2"]/div[4]

Is this website public? If yes, can you share the URL?

Hi @Shawn, unfortunately this website works only with the company domain.

The XPath expressions look OK to me(at least the first 2). Have you checked if the element is within an IFRAME? Can you share the relevant code and error/exception from the console?

Those 3 elements are siblings so which one is holding the action?, may be it's the parent element.

I have already tried all XPath, but it seems not working
Is there another way to inform the RPA that I need to click there?

I finally understood why it was not finding the xPath.
I needed to switch the window, since the previous command was opening a new window pop-up, the robot was not able to understand that.
